# Schedule notifications based on user time zone

Tags: android, ios, firebase, notifications, timezone

I'm building a simple calendar-like app with Firebase ( firestore as the db ). My users can create recurring "events" and set multiple reminders for each event, which should fire notifications for every event occurrence. Every event is private, and the user that created an event is the only one who should receive reminders notifications.

I'm storing the event start time as a unix timestamp and notifications as a map where keys are short ids and values are the time difference between the start date and the notification time ( in minutes, multiples of 5 ).

An event document looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "Example",
  "start": "1604962800000",
  "interval": 30, // event recurs every 30 days 
  "notifications": {
    "id1": 360, // the same day at 6 pm
    "id2": 1980, // the day before at 3 pm
    "id3": 3720, // two days before at 10 am
  }
  ...
}
```

I've excluded local notifications because user data are tied to the account and the user may change device at any time.

To send notifications I came up with this approach:

Every time an event document is created/updated a cloud function gets triggered and the next notification timestamp is calculated and saved in the "next" field of the document object.

Then, in another function triggered by cloud scheduler every 5 minutes I just query by the next field and for every event I send the notification and then calculate the next timestamp and save it.

This is probably a horrible approach, and I realized that it doesn't consider an eventual time zone shift by the user, or a time shift in the actual timezone ( due to daylight saving time ).

I've considered to store the user timezone. The problem is, I'm not sure about compatibility between android/ios available time zones and javascript supported ones ( for example `Asia/Hanoi` is available on android but not supported by `Intl.DateTimeFormat` in node ), and I don't want to constantly take care of timezones changes.

I also considered a task queue approach, with something like Cloud Tasks, but it seems to be rather difficult to manage tasks queues which might be updated/deleted at any time. Maybe this is the way to go?

Whatever approach I come up with or think about I feel like there must be something I'm missing,  maybe a flaw in my data model, because this is such a common use-case and I doubt everyone is dealing with such fragile systems.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should store all the user-selected times as UTC times and based on the country selected by the user you handled it in the backend.

Comment: I guess storing unix timestamps is the same as utc, as both are timezone independent, right? Anyway, what you're suggesting gets easily too complex ( mostly because my approach is too complex and fragile already ) so I'll wait for someone to suggest something simpler, but thank you very much for the comment anyway!